# With TypeORM, trying to filter DB table by age of data. The table doesn't contain age column (Age calculated with conditions). How to implement this?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

**Framework Using:** Nest.JS

**ORM Using:** TypeORM

**Database Using:** PostgreSQL

I am trying to implement a filter for user table, and the table contains columns like **createdDate**, **deactivatedDate**, **status(Active/Deactivated)**. I am trying to filter the user data by age, and the age is calculated by below conditions,

1. If user status is Active then the age is,
   **number of working days between "currentDate and createdDate".**
2. If user status is Deactivated then the age is,
   **number of working days between "deactivatedDate and createdDate".**

The working days are calculated by considering 5 working days in a week, then minus it with the number of holidays in between. I already wrote a typeScript function to calculate the working days between two dates (Passing the start and end dates as arguments and it fetch the holidays from the DB.).

What would be the ideal way to implement this with TypeORM?

Comment: my first option is to use sub-queries. something like below because the calculation have to be separated into 2 sections
`getManager().createQueryBuilder().select().from(qb => {//use subquery here to calculate age based on your condition and return user and age columns ...})`

Comment: Hi @AhmadDeel, Appriciate your suggestions, I tried this way but it was not working for me. So, I used ".addSelect(query, "alias") " inside the "Query Builder" for selecting the age. Then and filter it by executing the query through ".getManger()" and it's worked.